# Something is wrong with the November 2015 Moderator Election

Tags: bug, moderator-election

For each election on the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) the pattern seems to be:

- Usercards of Elected mods
- w voters were eligible, x visited the site during the election, y visited the election page, and z voted
- optional:

  - Usercards of called up mods
  - called up after the election to meet additional demand

See 2011:

[image: 2011]

In the November 2015 results the two text lines switched position:

[image: November 2015]

Once you've seen it, you can't keep your eyes of it.

Can the November 2015 election entry be edited so it matches the established layout or (less preferable) edit the other entries to match the November 2015 structure.

Thanks for being consistent.

Comment: Utmost importance

Comment: Not sure what's bothering me more: The swapped order of the text lines or the fact that your freehand "circle" is leaking uncontrollably: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H602d.png

Comment: OSCE observers needed stat

Comment: Unless there has been a regression between when the close voters closed this question and now, but for me this is not fixed and by that reason alone still reproducible. Are there lacking red free hand circles?